# Are iPhones on 3G connections "connectable?" Is 3g/wifi transparent when using sockets?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking, nat

I want to know if you can directly connect to an iPhone on a 3G connection using a TCP socket, or if there will be NAT problems.

In addition, will sending data over a socket be transparent to me as the programmer whether the user is using wifi or 3g?

Comment: 3g is laggy; it's designed for data throughput, not response time. So you need to be sure your application can function over 3g. Fast multiplayer games, for example, do not work well on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unless you explicitly check, you will never know the difference. However, it's obviously good practice to either warn the user or use less data if on cellular, because you don't want to eat all of their data.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know about the direct connection bit? Can I have a phone essentially act as a server in communication?

Comment: I didn't want to accept this one because you didn't answer the connectability problem, but you did help and nobody's answered.